# Failed to add play-services to android studio

Tags: android, google-play

I want to do a practice project that i can find my location by google map. at first i installed google play service lib :
[image]

second, I add FINE permission and mate tag on manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

third, I have added this lib on build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
```

but when i am syncing project< i got this error:

```
Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1
```

and `Avoid using bundled version of Google Play services SDK.`

what can i do? what any dependency i need?

Comment: Use separate API of google play services, that is more efficient than using whole package.

Comment: @Harmantj , i watched udacity video and they added `com.google.android.gms:play-services` and thay did not got any problem

Comment: I was also having the same problem, I used separate Apis(only required one) , it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement separate lib of google play services, that is more efficient than using the whole package. Use only required lib.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I added `    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6'
' and my problem gone.